# Windows 10 and Windows Phone 8.0 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-7-emulator

I installed Windows Phone 8.0 SDK on Windows 10. When I create a new Windows Phone 8.0 project I have no problem, but I have difficulties with a project for Windows Phone 7.1(Target Platform). After creating the project application, I can not choose the emulator for application deployment. Where there should be a list of emulators only "Start".

I tried to reinstall the SDK. But nothing helped. I even made a complete reset Windows 10.

Most likely it is related to the problem. When I open the project properties and I go to the debugging section, I see only error: HRESULT: 0x89721800

Answer (score 0):

Do you meet the requirements specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to fix this for a long time and I finally got the Windows Phone 8 emulator working on my Windows 10 device. I made sure that my Virtualization feature was turned on in my BIOS; I tried both VT-D on and off settings but it didn't matter on my machine. Then I must have repaired my installation and reinstalled Visual Studio like 10 times and it didn't work. Finally what did work was uninstalling all Silverlight installations on my computer, including the runtime. I manually downloaded Silverlight, Silverlight SDK 3, Silverlight SDK 4, and Silverlight SDK 5 from Microsoft. I then repaired my Windows Phone 8.0 SDK installation and opened a Windows Phone 8.0 app on VS 2012 Express for Windows Phone and I finally could see the emulators listed! I could even build and run my application! Unfortunately, I haven't been able to fix the Windows Phone 7 emulator, I get the same error as you. I tried two separate Windows 10 devices without success.  So what I do is just work on a Windows 7 device with Visual Studio 2010 for the Windows Phone 7 app.